# Meaning of "part" in the following sentence

Tags: usage

In the following sentence

> Mr. Gandhi’s letter of resignation is **part** self-reflection, about the Congress in general and his own personal role in it, and **part** a critique of the state of affairs of Indian politics.

Though I am able to comprehend this sentence but never saw such use of **part**

Is it grammatical?

Comment: This is a very common pattern in literary English, but the only dictionary I have found which even mentions it is in the OED, the single sentence "it is frequently used more than once in a sentence, forming a kind of correlative construction"..

Comment: In this usage "part" can be paraphrased as "partly" (or "partially").

Comment: It's in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/part) too, sense 4: "If you say that something is part one thing, part another, you mean that it is to some extent the first thing and to some extent the second thing."

Comment: [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/part) if you scroll down far enough has the example "The exam is part spoken and part written" although the definition is just a link to *partly*.

Answer (score 0):

If you try using the term *one half* instead you can see the meaning is the same. It is making a *partition* of the letter into its two goals. Describing a thing as part this and part that is typical English.

Answer (score 0):

The “part X, part Y” means that the letter can be divided into a part that contains X and a part that contains Y.

You see a similar construction in some recipes. For instance, a drink may be [made by combining] one part X and two parts Y. When there are numbers, they give a specific ratio of the listed ingredients. When there aren’t numbers, the ratio is unspecified.